# How do I limit the number of cores a user can access on a large shared windows 2019 server?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2019

I have a 64-core Windows 2019 Server. Several of my user's have badly written programs that never envisioned being on a shared machine, and use 100% CPU on all cores while doing no useful work with them. They're impacting all users, and as a form of damage control, I'd like to have at most 4 cores available to each logged in user (or 4 cores available to each app/process would be fine too). Is there a way to implement this on Windows Server 2019?

Comment: Are these "badly written programs" required for them to do their jobs? If these programs are not required for their jobs, and you are using AD, there is a way using group policy to block these programs (see: https://serverfault.com/questions/441555/how-can-i-prevent-a-specific-application-from-being-run-on-a-specific-machine-us ). If you are not using AD, you can do this using the registry. If they are required for their jobs, you could move each user to a VM using Hyper-V or similar. You can easily set the amount of resources used by each VM.

Comment: I'm using AD, and they are required unfortunately (think: cranky old science programs).